# Remove numbers from list but not those in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a list of list as follows

```
list_1 = ['what are you 3 guys doing there on 5th avenue', 'my password is 5x35omega44', 
          '2 days ago I saw it', 'every day is a blessing', 
          ' 345000 people have eaten here at the beach']
```

I want to remove 3, but not 5th or 5x35omega44. All the solutions I have searched for and tried end up removing numbers in an alphanumeric string, but I want those to remain as is. I want my list to look as follows:

```
list_1 = ['what are you guys doing there on 5th avenue', 'my password is 5x35omega44', 
          'days ago I saw it', 'every day is a blessing', 
          '  people have eaten here at the beach']
```

I am trying the following:

```
[' '.join(s for s in words.split() if not any(c.isdigit() for c in s)) for words in list_1]
```

Comment: You seem to need `re.sub(r'\b\d+\b', '', text)`

Comment: I assume a "number" is a string of consecutive digits that is neither preceded nor followed by a digit. You say you wish to remove numbers that are not "in an alphanumeric string". That means you do not wish to remove numbers that are preceded or followed by a letter. Therefore, in the string `"a 10 23_ 34%"`, `"10"` `"23"` and `"34"` would all be removed. You can do that by replacing matches of the following regex with empty strings: `(?i)(?<![a-z\d])\d+(?![a-z\d])`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/a9NmQj/1/). If that is not your intention you need to correct the statement of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the very helpful regex solutions provided, in a list comprehension format that I wanted, I was able to arrive at the following:

```
[' '.join([re.sub(r'\b(\d+)\b', '', item) for item in expression.split()]) for expression in list_1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use lookarounds to check if digits are not enclosed with letters or digits or underscores:

```
import re
list_1 = ['what are you 3 guys doing there on 5th avenue', 'my password is 5x35omega44', 
          '2 days ago I saw it', 'every day is a blessing', 
          ' 345000 people have eaten here at the beach']
for l in list_1:
  print(re.sub(r'(?<!\w)\d+(?!\w)', '', l))
```

Output:

```
what are you  guys doing there on 5th avenue
my password is 5x35omega44
 days ago I saw it
every day is a blessing
  people have eaten here at the beach
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VrykZh/1)**

Comment: Beautiful regex lookarounds!

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use try and except:

```
def is_intable(x):
    try:
        int(x)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

[' '.join([word for word in sentence.split() if not is_intable(word)]) for sentence in list_1]
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should be using regex. This will match numbers separated by word boundaries:

```
\b(\d+)\b
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/IDzke8/1) is a working example.

Some Python code may look like this:

```
import re
for item in list_1:
    new_item = re.sub(r'\b(\d+)\b', ' ', item)
    print(new_item)
```

I am not sure what the best way to handle spaces would be for your project. You may want to put `\s` at the end of the expression, making it `\b(\d+)\b\s` or you may wish to handle this some other way.

Comment: this works very well; I was looking to get the output back in a list format, like adding list comprehension to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isinstance(word, int)` function and get a shorter way to do it, you could try something like this:

```
[' '.join([word for word in expression.split() if not isinstance(word, int)]) for expression in list_1]

>>>['what are you guys doing there on 5th avenue', 'my password is 5x35omega44', 
   'days ago I saw it', 'every day is a blessing', 'people have eaten here at the beach']
```